# Normal function asking to be made Payable

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, arrays, struct, function

Below is the programme in solidity I wrote which assigns value to elements of an array.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.16 ;
 contract arr
 {
      uint i = 0 ;
     people[] public person ;

     struct people
     {
         uint256 num ;
         string name ;
     }

     function plus(string memory naam , uint256 nu) public
     {  
       person[i].num = nu ;
       person[i].name = naam ;
        i++ ;

     }
 }
```

Instead of push function I want to put values like this . While compilation and deploying no error comes however when I call this function then this error shows :-

[image]

It reads:-

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

I want to know what I am doing wrong , and why is it asking me to make the function payable.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It's because the 'person' creation is wrong so the tx reverts.

Here is the proper way:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.16 ;
 contract arr
 {
      uint i = 0 ;
     people[] public person ;

     struct people
     {
         uint256 num ;
         string name ;
     }

     function plus(string memory naam , uint256 nu) public
     {
       people memory olivier = people(nu, naam);
       person.push(olivier);
        i++ ;

     }
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah , by push opearor I am able to. I wanted to know why = is not working here ?

Comment: I think (not sure 100%) by doing "person[i].num = nu ;
" you assign 'nu' to 'person[0].num'. BUT person[0] doesn't exist! 'person' is an empty array of 'people'. So there is currently nothing at the memory location of person[0].num. You first need to push the newly made struct into the array 'person'. Hope that's more clear! If you could mark my first answer as valid that would be great!

Comment: Maybe you are right ....Thanks alot friend.